# How can I display an HtmlPage object (from HtmlUnit) to be opened in a real browser?

Tags: htmlunit, webautomation

I am using Htmlunit (browser automation/testing tool) to go through a series of links or perform a set of actions on a page. 
At some point after this I want to see the resulting page in a browser (internet explorer or firefox etc.)
How can I do this. ? Thank you Friends...

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you correctly.

This is my solution:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("http://stackoverflow.com/");

//Get page as Html
String htmlBody = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();

//Save the response in a file
String filePath = "c:/temp/out.html";
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));
bw.write(htmlBody);
bw.close();

//Open the page with a browser
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe " + filePath);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's probably cleaner to use the `java.awt.Desktop` API for opening the web browser, as I suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556796/).

The `Desktop.browse(URI)` and `Desktop.open(File)` will launch the default browser for the user's OS (which may be something other than IE even on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use htmlPage.save(File) (which automatically saves images) before executing real browser

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what he had in mind

```
//Get page as Html <br>
HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("http://stackoverflow.com/");

//create File object <br>
File file = new File("c://temp//out");

//save page image <br>
page.save(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

After saving the page to a file with the `HtmlPage.save(File)` method,
you can use the [`java.awt.Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API to open the file in its default application on your system (i.e. web browser if the file extension is ".html")

**Example:**

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://example.com/");
File file = File.createTempFile("example", ".html");
page.save(file);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

This should work on any OS/browser.

*Credit:* thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226244) for suggesting the `java.awt.Desktop` solution for launching a web browser.