# Opening a URL in the default browser

Tags: java, macos

I was wondering if there was a standard way to open URLs in the users default browser. I've been using the desktop.browse() way, but after a bit of testing I can't seem to make this work on OSX while it works fine on Windows. My attempts at research have brought up mostly old articles, so I thought there may be a more modern method I can't find. Ideally there would be one approach that could work for every system, but lacking that I can always make it branch off by system. So my questions are this:

- Is there an approach that opens up the default browser on any system to a specific URL?
- If not, then what are the best methods for doing this on OSX and
  Linux?

Comment: Okay, so I have decided to go with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open",url}); for OSX.  In a side note, if anyone was wondering, the reason the Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url)); did not work was because this was a JavaFX application using AWT. I'm assuming that under most other conditions, that method would work for any system without any hassle.

Answer (score 5):

[`java.awt.Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) is the class you're looking for.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

// ...

if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
  Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
}
```

That is what I would do. answer comes from this site at ::
[How to open the default webbrowser using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. My problem is that I am already using this method, but this does not seem to work on OSX, while it works perfectly on Windows. I will fiddle with it again, but it did not work the last few times I tried. If it IS supposed to work on OSX, I clearly messed something up.

Comment: the only other thing I could find/think of is

https://www.java.net//node/667183

and that is so old.