# Java user input to website

Tags: java, httprequest, user-input

Is it possible to write a program in java that allows you to type something like "Can you go to google?" and then have the program open your default webbrowser and go to google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open the default webbrowser using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java)

Comment: Perfect answer to this question: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using the [Desktop API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

> The Desktop class allows a Java application to launch associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a file.
>
> Supported operations include:
>
> - launching the user-default browser to show a specified URI;
> - launching the user-default mail client with an optional mailto URI;
> - launching a registered application to open, edit or print a specified file.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the webpage with your default browser with the following:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.ca"));
```

Dont forget to import java.awt.Desktop :)