# URL search through java program

Tags: java, google-chrome

Just a quick question. Part of a program I'm building with Java opens up Chrome. I was wondering if after the program opened Chrome, there would be a way to search a specific URL or just regular keywords (example: recipes, images, or to just Google a question.)

Comment: Check this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18509384/364474)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this code below.But this will only work on Windows

```
String question="what is this?";

        question= question.replace(' ', '+');


        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start chrome https://www.google.com/search?q="+question});
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```