# Java equivalent to Python's webbrowser.open()

Tags: java, python, equivalent, python-webbrowser

I just finished a project with Python and now I am trying to convert it into Java. I have a lot of things done but I am stuck on this one part. In python, I am opening a random link from a list on the web browser with this code

```
import webbrowser

urls = [# list of URLs]
url_to_open = random.choice(urls)
webbrowser.open(url_to_open)
```

In Java I was able to replicate the choosing of the random URL, but I am not sure how to open the URL in the web browser.

So, **what is the Java equivalent to Python `webbrowser.open()`?**

Comment: Google and ye shall receive: [How to open the default webbrowser using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.awt.Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) has this facility.