# how to open new browser window from java desktop application code?

Tags: java, browser, new-window

I want to open new browser window from java desktop application. If browser is already open, then new browser window should open. Every time it should open a separate window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java

Comment: this will open a new tab in default browser. I want to open new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows, this should do the trick:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://www.google.com");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: as my browser is already opened, i want to open a separate window. It is opening a new tab in the already opened window.

Comment: ah ok...but it's a good option if good performance is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The builtin mechanism for "opening a browser" would be

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://your.link..."))
```

Starting a new window / process each time might only be possible if you *know* the browser being used and know of a parameter to pass to always create new window.