# Java program closing before Scanner can take input 2nd time around

Tags: java, jsoup, java.util.scanner, runtime.exec

I am experimenting with JSoup, and I cannot get my 2nd go-around with my Scanner to work. It skips directly to my catch statement.

Here is a description of the program:

I take a google search term as user input (String). Next, I ask for the number of query items that the user wishes to see, and enter an integer.

I loop through each element that is returned and add it to an ArrayList. The String displayed on the console consists of an index, Link Text, and a hyperlink.

I then want to ask the user which index they would like to enter to open a browser window leading to that link. This is done by cocantenating the hRef string with the Linux terminal command "xdg-open " using the Runtime class.

It works great up until it's time to ask which index will be chosen.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Created by christopher on 4/26/16.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class GoogleSearchJava {

    static int index;
    static String linkHref;
    static Scanner input;

    public static final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //GET INPUT FOR SEARCH TERM

        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Search: ");
        String searchTerm = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of query results: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + searchTerm + "&num=" + num;

        //NEED TO DEFINE USER AGENT TO PREVENT 403 ERROR.
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();

        //OPTION TO DISPLAY HTML FILE IN BROWSWER. DON'T KNOW YET.
        //System.out.println(doc.html());

        //If google search results HTML change the <h3 class="r" to <h3 class ="r1"
        //need to change below stuff accordingly
        Elements results = document.select("h3.r > a");

        index = 0;
        String news = "News";
        ArrayList<String> displayResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element result : results) {
            index++;
            linkHref = result.attr("href");
            String linkText = result.text();
            String pingResult = index + ": " + linkText + ", URL:: " + linkHref.substring(6, linkHref.indexOf("&")) + "\n";

            if (pingResult.contains(news)) {
                System.out.println("FOUND " + "\"" + linkText + "\"" + "NO HYPERTEXT FOR NEWS QUERY RESULTS AT THIS TIME. SKIPPED INDEX.");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                displayResults.add(pingResult);
            }
        }
        for(String urlString : displayResults) {
            System.out.println(urlString);
        }
        System.out.println();

        goToURL(input, displayResults);
    }
    public static int goToURL(Scanner input, ArrayList<String> resultList) {

        int newIndex = 0;

        try {

            System.out.print("Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: ");

            newIndex = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();

            for (String string : resultList) {

                if(string.startsWith(String.valueOf(newIndex))) {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open " + string.substring(6, string.indexOf("&")));
                    process.waitFor();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR while parsing URL");
        }
        return newIndex;
    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE OUTPUT** Notice how it stops after I enter "1" No, I haven't taken care of pressing "0" yet:

```
Search: Oracle
Enter number of query results: 3
1: Oracle | Integrated Cloud Applications and Platform Services, URL:: =http://www.oracle.com/

2: Oracle Corporation - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia, URL:: =https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation

3: Oracle on the Forbes America's Best Employers List, URL:: =http://www.forbes.com/companies/oracle/


Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: 1
ERROR while parsing URL

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR while parsing URL` suggests that error comes from

```
try {

    System.out.print("Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: ");

    newIndex = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    for (String string : resultList) {

        if(string.startsWith(String.valueOf(newIndex))) {

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open " + string.substring(6, string.indexOf("&")));
            process.waitFor();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR while parsing URL");
}
```

I am not working on Linux so I can't test it but I suspect that your url shoulnd't start with `=` (you will notice that your console contains `URL:: =...` where your printing statement doesn't have this `=` so it is part of address you are trying to visit).

So change in `.substring(6, hRef.indexOf("&"))` `6` to `7`.

---

Other problem is that `hRef` is set to be `linkHref` which will be last result from google you picked. You should probably create your own class which will store proper href and its description, or pass list of `Element` representing `<a ...>..</a>` elements which you picked (also you don't need to check elements in list based on their `1: ...` format, simply use `list.get(index - 1)` if you want to map 1 to index 0, 2 to index 1 and so on).

---

Last advice for now is that you may change your code to be more OS independent with solution described here [How to open the default webbrowser using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java) rather than trying to execute `xdg-open`

Comment: I got the Desktop class code working from the above link, but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion for the linkHRef variable.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I tried to simply your code a little. You can find it here http://pastebin.com/VTNey8H8 (I don't want to add full solution here as it would make this answer too broad).

Comment: Go ahead and post your code here. I tried it out and it works PERFECTLY. I will gladly accept your answer. :)

Comment: One problem, though. If I change the number to 5, it gives me 8 query results. ??????? But your answer still answered my initial question.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I am not sure what you mean. If I set `int num = 5;` then your query will add `&num=5` parameter which should set max results to 5.

Comment: I replaced '3' with '5', and this was my output: 

1 Oracle | Integrated Cloud Applications and Platform Services
2 Oracle Careers
3 Oracle Database
4 About Oracle
5 Support
6 Downloads
7 Java
8 Oracle Corporation - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you here. Maybe it is google which handles differently parameters provided in URL. Try printing your `searchURL` and visit it using your browser. See if it will really contain 8 results.

Comment: I fixed it. At the line "for(Element a : filteredResults)" I added a while loop with the condition while(index <= num), and it achieved the results.

Comment: It is way around, but it is strange tat you are getting this results in the first place.