# Open a specific browser with Jython

Tags: java, browser, jython, runtime.exec, jython-2.7

I would like to open a specific browser with **Jython**.

I believe this is [how it is done with **Java**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51662836/10936066):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start chrome http://www.stackoverflow.com"});
```

---

I've tried to convert the Java to **Jython**:

```
from java.lang import Runtime 
Runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
Runtime.exec("start chrome http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

However, it fails:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified in <script> at line number 3
BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the TESTURL script for the LP23 launch point from running.
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system 
cannot find the file specified in <script> at line number 3
```

---

**Is it possible to open a specific browser with Jython?**

Comment: Note: In my implementation of Jython (Maximo 7.6.1.1), it is **not** possible to import Python libraries.

Comment: `Runtime.exec("cmd /c start chrome http://www.stackoverflow.com")` works for me (but I'm not using Maximo).

Comment: Related question here: [Jython: Open URL in browser (without importing Python libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488528/jython-open-url-in-browser-without-importing-python-libraries/58497638#58497638])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jython: Open URL in browser (without importing Python libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488528/jython-open-url-in-browser-without-importing-python-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is, "No."

Because Automation Scripts run 100% on the server side (even on the server-side of the server-side), they have zero direct control over the client / browser. You could format a URL into an attribute and use that attribute for a Launch in Context configuration item, but that's about as close as you come to manipulating the client / browser, unless you want to do a much more invasive customization.

Comment: Have you ever seen a hyperlink in a Maximo message box? Or a button in a message box that had some code behind it?

Comment: I think I've put one in a "maxmessage" (Messages option in DB Config) that was used somewhere, but that memory is a bit foggy. I would certainly try it again. I know I have put `<br/>` tags in those.