# Java: Open URL in browser WITHOUT using AWT

Tags: java, awt, lwjgl

I need to open a link in my web browser using Java, but the stipulation is that I can't use `java.awt.Desktop` to do it. The reason why is because I'm trying to do this from an LWJGL3 program, and using AWT in its context will cause the program to not work on Mac systems.

So basically, I need the functionality of `Desktop.browse(URL)` without AWT. Does anyone know of some third party application or something I can use that can do this (or how I can potentially do it myself).

Thank you!

Comment: One obvious suggestion is to use either [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) or [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: But that should work on a Mac (I'm on a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question at these two links.

Open the links with pure Java:
[How to open the default webbrowser using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java/28807079#28807079)

A comment on the subject by the maintainer of LWJGL3:
http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6872.0