# Open telephone number link

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, tel

I want to open MS Teams to dial a number like on a HTML webpage with the `<a href="tel:.....` tag.
As far as I know, the HTML Version in Java is very old and maybe `tel:` is not supported in the included version. However, I tried this code which is working fine for normal HMTL links.

```
String st = "<html>\r\n<a href=\"tel:+4917312345678\">0173 12345678</a>\r\n</html>";
editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", st);
// handle link events
editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED))
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } // roll your own link launcher or use Desktop if J6+
    }
});
editorPane.setEditable(false);
editorPane.setBounds(72, 244, 423, 137);
panel_3.add(editorPane);
```

but this doesn't work for `tel:` links

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toURI()" because the return value of "javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent.getURL()" is null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a way how I can use tel: links.
My Code is only for windows so if you want to use if cross platform you have to do a check before like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java)

```
    String st = "<html>\r\n<a href=\"tel:+4917312345678\">+4917312345678</a>\r\n</html>";
    editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", st);
    // handle link events
    editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        @Override
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED))
                    try {
                        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        String url = e.getDescription();
                        System.out.println(url);
                        rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    });
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    editorPane.setBounds(72, 244, 423, 137);
    panel_3.add(editorPane);
```